# How to install applications on playbook from appworld?

Tags: mobile, blackberry, blackberry-playbook

How to install applications on playbook from appworld? I have installed the simulator but I did not fid any way to install some application from appworld.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean how to install applications from App World on the simulator, then it cannot be done unless you contact the author and obtain the .bar file directly from them.  Then you use the regular SDK tools to install the .bar file (e.g. `blackberry-deploy`).

The simulator does not support App World, and may never support it.